# Django - OperationalError, No such table: accounts_user

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views, django-forms

I'm working on a Django backend for a simple to-do list website. The website authenticates users by asking them to put in their email, sending them a link with a token, then using that token to log them in when they click on the link, redirecting them back to the homepage.

When I try and run the development server, I always get a debug screen saying `OperationalError at /` `no such table: accounts_user`. I have two apps that are part of the overall project, `lists` and `accounts`.

Solutions to similar errors I've come across on StackOverflow haven't worked for me. Both apps are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` under `core.settings`. I tried deleting my sqlite database, all my `__pycache__` and `migrations` folders, and running `makemigrations` and `migrate` again, to no avail. I even ran it for the `accounts` app, and ran it using `--run-syncdb`, and that still didn't work.

The error is thrown during template rendering, on line 17 of my `base.py`, specifically the one that says, `{% if user.email %}`.

**I'm using Django 1.11.29 and Python 3.6.8. The database is a simple sqlite file in the project directory.**

Here's my models and views, along with the website's base template:

`lists/models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class List(models.Model):
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('view_list', args=[self.id])

class Item(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    ordering = ('id',)
    unique_together = ('list', 'text',)
  
  def __str__(self):
    return self.text
  
  text = models.TextField(default='')
  list = models.ForeignKey(List, default=None)
```

`lists/views.py`

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.html import escape

from lists.forms import ExistingListItemForm, ItemForm
from lists.models import Item, List

def home_page(request):
  return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': ItemForm()})

def new_list(request):
  form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
  
  if form.is_valid():
    list_ = List.objects.create()
    form = ItemForm(data=request.POST)
    form.add_list(list_)
    form.save()
    return redirect(list_)
  else:
    return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form})

def view_list(request, list_id):
  list_ = List.objects.get(id=list_id)
  form = ExistingListItemForm(for_list=list_)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ExistingListItemForm(for_list=list_, data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect(list_)
  
  return render(request, 'list.html', {'list': list_, "form": form})
```

`accounts/models.py`

```py
import uuid

from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.db.utils import OperationalError

try:
  auth.signals.user_logged_in.disconnect(auth.models.update_last_login)
except OperationalError:
  pass

class User(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
  
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  is_anonymous = False
  is_authenticated = True

class Token(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  uid = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=40)
```

`accounts/views.py`

```py
import uuid

from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.db.utils import OperationalError

try:
  auth.signals.user_logged_in.disconnect(auth.models.update_last_login)
except OperationalError:
  pass

class User(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
  
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  is_anonymous = False
  is_authenticated = True

class Token(models.Model):
  email = models.EmailField()
  uid = models.CharField(default=uuid.uuid4, max_length=40)
```

`lists/templates/base.py`

```py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>To-Do lists</title>
    <link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class"container">
      
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Superlists</a>
          {% if user.email %}
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="navbar-text">Logged in as {{ user.email }}</li>
              <li><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
          {% else %}
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right"
            method="POST"
            action="{% url 'send_login_email' %}">
              <span>Enter email to log in:</span>
              <input class="form-control" name="email" type="text" />
              {% csrf_token %}
            </form>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </nav>

      {% if messages %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            {% for message in messages %}
              {% if message.level_tag == 'success' %}
                <div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>
              {% else %}
                <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ message }}</div>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 jumbotron">
          <div class="text-center">
            <h1>{% block header_text %}{% endblock %}</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="{% block form_action %}{% endblock %}">
              {{ form.text }}
              {% csrf_token %}
              {% if form.errors %}
                <div class="form-group has-errors">
                  <span class="help-block">{{ form.text.errors }}</span>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          {% block table %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="/static/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/list.js"></script>

    <script>

      $(document).ready(function() {
        window.Superlists.initialize();
      });
      
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you migrate your accouts app? ```python manage.py makemigrations accounts```?

Comment: @ha-neul yeah, I did

Answer (score 4):

If you've changed some names in your model class, check if those names are still kept in your migrations files and potentially change them manually. Try to migrate again and see what happens.

Worst case scenario, delete migrations folder and the database file, make migrations, and migrate again.

In some cases, you'd have to sync your database, so add this command after the migrate keyword `--run-syncdb`.